# C# Linq Where and Regex

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have 4 rows in my DB (example), I load data from DB to DataModel like Regex for columns Code and Serie:

```
Id;Code;Serie
1;XXX;XXX
2;XXX;XXX_A
3;WWW;YYY_A|YYY_B
4;CCC;XXX_A
```

When I use LINQ query below with input parameters **Code = XXX** and **Serie = XXX_A**, I got 2 results, but the right result is only got a row with ID == 2

```
model = _seriesData.Where(s => (s.Code.IsMatch(code) && s.Type.IsMatch(serie)));
```

I do not know where is a problem, but LINQ works only with one parameter

***In my model column Code and Serie are Regex types***

**UPDATE**

For Code row Regex I also use regex like this XXX_A|XXX_B|YYY_A
Data in the _seriesData variable are ok, but the result is wrong

**DataModel**

```
public class SerieModel
{
    public Regex Type { get; set; } // name of serie
    public Regex Code { get; set; }
}
```

Does anybody help me?

Comment: Bear in mind that almost any function call in a `.Where` clause will cause the data to be retrieved from the database and the clause will run locally.   This may involve huge numbers of records being sent over your network and be very inefficient.

Comment: Seems weird! If you test with .equals or '==' what do you get?

Comment: Try this:  model = _seriesData.Where(s => (s.Code==code && s.Serie==serie)).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Use FirstOrDefault(); is not a solution because I do not know if my row which I want to find is first in DB or not, also == is not possible to use for Regex datatype, Type and Serie is same, only with another names

Comment: You should one use Regex when string class methods cannot be used.  Regex is much less efficient than string class.  All  you need is a simple comparison : model = _seriesData.Where(s => (s.Code == code) && (s.Type == serie));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens probably because your regex matches **substring** but not **whole string**. Whole string is matched by wrapping your pattern in `^...$` symbols:

```
new Regex("XXX").IsMatch("XXX");     //true
new Regex("XXX").IsMatch("XXX_A");   //true <- heh, didn't expect that?
new Regex("^XXX$").IsMatch("XXX");   //true
new Regex("^XXX$").IsMatch("XXX_A"); //false <- this is what you want
```

So, either change data in your columns to:

```
Id;Code;Serie
1;^XXX$;^XXX$
2;^XXX$;^XXX_A$
3;^WWW$;^(YYY_A|YYY_B)$
4;^CCC$;^XXX_A$
```

Or change it on deserialization to row:

```
public class SerieModel
{
    public Regex Type { get; set; } // <- put here wrapped regex.
    public Regex Code { get; set; } // <- put here wrapped regex.
}
```